# Using an intent just to send data without moving to a different class/activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a method set up to send data to my MainActivty:

```
public void sendPlayerDataMethod() {
    String testt = "thissss is for testing";
    Intent sendPlayerData = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    sendPlayerData.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, testt);
    startActivity(sendPlayerData);
}
```

Every time this method is called, it then takes the user to the MainActivity, as coded but how do I get it to just send the data without moving to another activity?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use `SharedPreferenceClass`

Comment: If you need to access those data frequently then you can use `static` variable. or use SharedPreferences (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Where do you wanna send it to?

Comment: @greenapps the destination is actually MainAcitivty.class

Comment: That is the class definition. But is there already an activity running of that class? Or how? What do you have in mind?

Comment: @greenapps It's ok, the below response has answered this question, thanks for your help though!

Comment: @greenapps The way I put the question was incorrect and I did not explain it well enough but I did get the answer I needed. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from what you wrote : You have an activity called MainActivity it is open and you are trying to send data to it from another activity.

Try this if this suits your case :

Add this to your MainActivity in your manifest : `android:launchMode="singleTask"` 
This will prevent your activity from instantiating again and again.

Override this method on your MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
   super.onNewIntent(intent);
   //get and use your extra data
}
```

now when you call your activity via an intent, this onNewIntent method will be fired. Get your extra data there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But it still will go to that activity isnt it?

Comment: Thanks for this answer.